# unix replace dynamic filenames with dynamic strings

Tags: xml, unix, filenames

I am new in unix and need to do followings:
I have 10 files with name:

```
t1_20160322_load_8977854_49843489_1.xml
t1_20160322_load_8977855_47536364_1.xml
t1_20160322_load_8977856_93435735_1.xml
t1_20160322_load_8977857_78637575_1.xml
t1_20160322_load_8977858_97437542_1.xml
....
```

and I received one a file (loadnumber.txt) with following content:

```
8977854;EUROLOADSAMPLE;c
8977855;ASIENLOADSAMPLE;i
8977856;AFRICANLOADSAMPLE;s
8977857;USALOADSAMPLE;l
8977858;CANADALOADSAMPLE;o
```

I need to replace the number with value from the text file, for example the file t1_20160322_load_8977854_49843489_1.xml should be changed to

```
t1_EUROLOADSAMPLE_c.xml
```

and the file t1_20160322_load_8977854_49843489_1.xml should be changed to `t1_ASIENLOADSAMPLE_i.xml`

I tried to google how to write the unix commando, but I think I am missing the basic knowledge, so I wrote followings:

```
for f in $(t1*xml);do;for x in $(cat contracts_generator.txt);do;g=$(echo $x | cut -d\; -f1); n=$(echo $x | cut -d\; -f2); m=$(echo $x | cut -d\; -f3);mv $f t1_$n.xml;done;done
```

This didn't work of course. Can you please help me to figure out, how I should write the code?

Thank you so much for your answers in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to understand something, you should create a shell script to handle your issue. Create a file called myscript.sh with your content.

Your where not too far, so I fixed it so:

```
    for f in $(ls t1*xml)
    do
       #echo $f
       mymatch=$(echo $f |cut -d"_" -f4)
       #echo $mymatch

       for x in $(cat contracts_generator.txt)
       do
          g=$(echo $x | cut -d\; -f1)
          if [[ "$g" == "$mymatch" ]]
          then
             n=$(echo $x | cut -d\; -f2)
             m=$(echo $x | cut -d\; -f3)
          fi
       done
       mv ${f} t1_${n}_${m}.xml
   done
```

(remove `#` before the `echo` for debug)

Then call your script so:

```
sh myscript.sh
```